# use contact form with php but msg is empty

Tags: php, email, submit, send, contacts

i use this form

```
<form action="form.php" method="post">
    <input name="name" type="text" value="اسمك الكريم" onblur="if (this.value=='')this.value='اسمك الكريم'" onclick="value=''" />
    <br />
    <input name="email" type="text" value="البريد الالكتروني" />
    <br />
    <input name="phone" type="text" value="رقم الهاتف" onblur="if (this.value=='')this.value='رقم الهاتف'" onclick="value=''" />
    <br />
    <textarea name="نص الرساله" cols="41" rows="5" placeholder="نص الرساله" wrap=soft></textarea>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="ارسال" />
</form>
```

and php file

```
<?php
$webmaster_mail = 'sales@elfnoon.com';
$message_subject = 'رسالة من زائر لموقعك';

$in_Body ='';
    foreach($HTTP_POST_VARS as $in_k=>$in_v)
    {
$in_Body .="$in_k = $in_v\n\n";
    }
mail(trim($webmaster_mail), "$message_subject ", "$in_Body","From: " . trim($webmaster_mail));
?>
```

but after i got msg is empty

why this problem??

and if this problem for i use htaccess to convert url from php to html

Comment: use `$_POST` instead of `$HTTP_POST_VARS`

Comment: thx now work fine but how to get info of sender like ip religion brower etc.. ??

Comment: how to add like echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; in php code

Answer (score 1):

`$HTTP_POST_VARS` is old and some new versions don't have it activated, use the new `$_POST` instead, it's just the same but shorter.

Comment: thx now work fine
but how to get info of sender like ip religion brower etc.. ??

Comment: Don't forget to mark as answered. That's a different question, read this: http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=1028597 browser don't send religion by itself so you have to ask it adding more input fields.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the input must begin with a letter (ASCII character set) followed by alphanumerics, hyphen, underscore, colon and/or period. You'll need to change the name of the text area.

Comment: thx now work fine but how to get info of sender like ip religion brower etc.. ??